# Nullable Datetime in .NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view which is used for "Create" and "Update" a database model. The database model has a property which is a `DateTime?` (nullable). Now I am trying to use this nullable datetime in an ASP.NET Core MVC view which looks like the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyNullableDate,"{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { placeholder = "dd.MM.yyyy", @class = "form-control form-control-sm", type = "date" })
```

This works very well for the "Create" process. If a date is set, it is written correctly into the database. But now I want to update the already existing database value `model.MyNullableDate`.

I read the value from the database and pass the value again to the view. The property `MyNullableDate` is set correctly and I saw in the debugger that the correct date is written into it.

But in the view, nothing is shown... it's only an empty textbox without the passed in value of `MyNullableDate`.

The property looks like this:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? MyNullableDate{ get; set; }
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I show the value of `MyNullableDate` in the `TextBoxFor`?

Comment: Why is the placeholder format (`mm/dd/yyyy`) different from the one used in `DataFormatString` (`dd.MM.yyyy`)? Also, you've probably meant `MM` instead of `mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the date format rather than the nullability.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

> The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — the
>   displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser,
>   but the parsed value is **always formatted yyyy-mm-dd**.

When I passed the `format` as below, the date displayed :)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    expression: model => model.MyNullableDate, 
    format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", 
    htmlAttributes: new
    {
        placeholder = "dd.MM.yyyy", 
        @class = "form-control form-control-sm", 
        type = "date"
    })
```